# Rpart vs Caret Cross Validation for Complexity Parameter

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, r-caret, rpart

I have a few questions about the difference between Rpart and Caret (using Rpart):

1. When using Rpart to fit a decision tree, calling dt$cptable displays a table of complexity parameters and their associated cross-validation errors. When pruning a tree, we would want to select the CP with the lowest cross-validation error. How are these cross-validation errors calculated? In reading Rpart's vignette, it seems like RPart does the following:

   a) Fits the full tree based on the user-specified parameters. As the tree is being built, the algorithm calculates the complexity parameter at each split

   b) The algorithm then splits the data into k folds, and for each CP, basically just performs cross-validation using these folds. Then it calculates the average error across all of the folds to get the 'xerror' output we see in CP$table
2. If we were to use caret with cross validation to find the optimal tree, how is it running? Basically, is the algorithm splitting the dataset into k folds, then calling the Rpart function, and for each call of the Rpart function doing the same thing described in point 1 above? In other words, is it using cross-validation within cross-validation, whereas Rpart is just using cross-validation once?

Below is some code, even though I'm asking more about how the algorithm functions, maybe it will be useful:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(caret)
set.seed(100)
data.class <- data.termlife[, 2:ncol(data.termlife)]
data.class$TERM_FLAG <- as.factor(data.class$TERM_FLAG)

train.indices <- createDataPartition(data.class$TERM_FLAG, p = .8, list = FALSE)

data.class.t <- data.class[train.indices, ]
data.class.v <- data.class[-train.indices, ]

#Using Rpart
rpart.ctrl <- rpart.control(minsplit = 5, minbucket = 5, cp = .01)
f <- as.formula(paste0("TERM_FLAG ~ ", paste0(names(data.class.t)[2:9], collapse = "+")))
dt <- rpart(formula = f, data = data.class.t, control = rpart.ctrl, parms = list(split = "gini"))
cp.best.rpart <- dt$cptable[which.min(dt$cptable[, "xerror"]), "CP"]

#Using Caret
train.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
tGrid <- expand.grid(cp = seq(0, .02, .0001))

dt.caret <- train(form = f, data = data.class.t, method = "rpart", metric = "Accuracy", trControl = train.ctrl, tuneGrid = tGrid)

cp.best.caret <- dt.caret$bestTune$cp

print(paste("Rpart's best CP: ", cp.best.rpart))
print(paste("Caret's best CP: ", cp.best.caret))
```

```
[1] "Rpart's best CP:  0.0194444444444444"
[1] "Caret's best CP:  0.02"
```

The results are very similar, so when would you ever want to use Caret with Rpart? Thank you!!!

Comment: How would one use rpart and get the cp which maximizes AUC for instance? What if one wanted to tune `minsplit` and `minbucket` to maximize AUC? They would have to write their own wrapper around rpart and this is why caret exists. It allows flexibility in defining and evaluating models while maintaining a unified syntax across all machine learning algorithms.

Comment: That's a good point - I didn't think about that. I guess, more specifically, if the parameters you mentioned were not being tuned, there would be statistically be no difference between building the tree using rpart or caret?

Comment: The only difference would be due to different data splits during CV, which one can control in `caret`. Not sure if folds can be defined in `rpart`.